# How to generate documentation for models in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rdoc

I want to generate documentation for my rails application. The application has models with relationship(e.g. has_many relation) and I am looking for a way to generate documentation that shows the relation between models. Ideally, with some graphs those represent the relationships between models.

Is there a way to achieve this in rails 3.2x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [rails-erd gem](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd). It generates entity-relationship diagrams from your models.

The [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) IDE also does it on the fly, but it's not free.

Comment: I meant something for free :)